# How to store error/warning logs from the closure compiler output

Tags: logging, gruntjs, google-closure-compiler

I'm using `grunt` with the `google-closure-compiler` node module, when I run the task I've receive a set of warnings/errors, it is OK to have them in the command line window when there are few of them but sometimes there are a bunch of warnings that doesnt fit the window buffer so they are lost.

How can I log this into a file so I can then review the file and have it all safe? This is my grunt task

```
    'closure-compiler': {
        my_target: {
            files: {
                '<%= buildDir %>js/<%= outputName %>.min.js': [
                    '<%= sourceDir %>js/namespace.js',
                     //  list of files to process
              ]
            },
            options: {
                externs: ['<%= sourceDir %>externs/signals-externs-1.0.0b268.js', '<%= sourceDir %>externs/pixi-3.0.8-externs.js', '<%= sourceDir %>externs/jquery-externs-1.9.js'],
                compilation_level: 'ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS',
                language_in: 'ECMASCRIPT5_STRICT',
                create_source_map: '<%= buildDir %>js/<%= outputName %>.min.js.map',
                output_wrapper: '%output%\n//# sourceMappingURL=<%= outputName %>.min.js.map',
                'summary_detail_level': 3,
                debug: true,
                formatting: 'PRETTY_PRINT',
                warning_level: 'VERBOSE'
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be quite easy - when you know what you are looking for in first place:)

The answer (possibly not the only) is to use [logfile-grunt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/logfile-grunt) module

to install:

`npm install logfile-grunt --save-dev` and then

all you have to do in your Gruntfile.js is to add this line:

`require('logfile-grunt')(grunt);`

and output will also be logged in to the file placed here: `./logs/grunt.log`